# Trouble With Division Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mips

I'm currently trying to code a function to divide integers in MIPS. I am supposed to use a division algorithm using this flowchart:

[image: Division Algorithm Flowchart]

Here is the code that I have created:

```
.data

.text 

main:

addi $a0, $0, 7
addi $a1, $0, 4
jal divide
addi $a0, $v1, 0
addi $v0, $0, 1
syscall

addi $v0, $0, 10
syscall

divide: # $a0/$s0 = Dividend-Remainder / $a1/$s1 = Divisor / $v1 =      Quotient
# Initialize
addi $s0, $a0, 0
addi $s1, $a1, 0
addi $t0, $0, 0 # Counter = $t0
addi $t1, $0, 33 # Number of loops = $t1

# Start of loop
start:
# Step 1 : Subtract the divisor register from the remainder register     and place in remainder register
sub $s0, $s0, $s1
# Step 2 : Test the remainder register. If < 0 go to part B, otherwise go to part A
addi $t3, $0, 0
slt $t2, $t3, $s0
beq $t2, $zero, partB
# Step 2A : Shift quotient register to the left, and make least significant bit 1
sll $v1, $v1, 1
ori $v1, $v1, 1
j after # Skip step 2B
# Step 2B : Add divisor to remainder and place sum in remainder register 
partB:
add $s0, $s1, $s0
# Shift quotient register to left and make least significant bit 0
sll $v1, $v1, 1
after:
# Step 3 : Shift divisor right 1 bit
srl $s1, $s1, 1
# Increment counter
addi $t0, $t0, 1
# Test loop
bne $t0, $t1, start
jr $ra
```

I've been trying to catch my error but so far I have been unable to find it. When I run the code I get -1073741825 for the output.

Can someone check my logic and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If there's no output, either your syscall is wrong, or your code is looping somewhere. Which is it?

Comment: @PaulHankin I rewrote the code. Now the output that I am getting is -1073741825

Comment: Try single-stepping and see where the program diverges from what you think it should do.